# Does balanced payment api validate these?

Tags: validation, payment, balanced-payments

does api validate balanced payment

1. social security number
2. address
3. account number
4. legal name
5. EIN
6. Date of birth
   if yes, then how??

Answer (score 1):

There are a two separate validation processes, one that occurs on the Customer resource and then on the Funding Instrument.

**1) Customer**

For customer identity verification: https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/resources/#customer-identity-verification

The customer identity verification is run through a 3rd party identification service each time the customer resource information is saved or updated, and is pertinent to underwriting merchants that are being paid out to.

**2) Funding Instrument**
For address verification: https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/resources/#address-verification-service-avs

Furthermore the Name, CVV, Postal_code, and Country Code fields are critical to reducing both fraud and declinations. These fields are checked by the banks, but do not result in hard failures. More info can be found here: https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/best-practices/#reducing-declined-transactions

Please note that even if a customer object has name or address data this is not passed on to the card object when associated.